# Probability of point $P$ in the unit square

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is a question for from the book  Intro. to Probability (Grinstead & Snell) Sec. 5.2 Exercise. 13:

**Question:**
A point $P$ in the unit square has coordinates $X$ and $Y$ chosen at random in
the interval $[0; 1]$. Let $D$ be the distance from $P$ to the nearest edge of the
square, and $E$ the distance to the nearest corner. What is the probability
that

- $D < 1/4$
- $E < 1/4$

*My Progress so far:*
Given we know $$ 0 \leq Y \leq 1 $$ and $$ 0 \leq X \leq 1 $$
I thought $$D = 
\Big\{ 1-Y, Y < X \ or \  1 - X,\ X<Y \Big\}$$
And for the distance to the nearest corner should be: 
$$E = \sqrt{(1-Y)^2 + (1-X)^2} $$

I am still trying to wrap my mind around random variables, so I am not a 100% sure on how to proceed from here. It would be great if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Assuming that the point $P$ is chosen *uniformly* from the unit square (that detail is important), then the probability of it being in any region is proportional to the area of that region—is in fact equal to the area of that region in this case, since $P$ is drawn from the unit square.  Once you properly draw the regions, just compute their areas, and those are the desired probabilities. ¶ Your expressions don't look right, though.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Didn't think about it in terms of areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the crude picture, but here's some intuition:

[image]

What you want is the area of the *intersection* of the blue and red regions.

(If this is, in fact, not what you want, you can use the pictures separately: the blue region is $D < \frac14$, the red region is $E < \frac14$)

How did I find each region?

For the blue region, go to each edge and find all points that are less than 0.25 units away from this edge. Repeat for all four edges. There will be some overlap but it doesn't really matter, and your area ends up being a "2D frustrum" of a square.

For the red region, go to each corner and find all points that are less than 0.25 units away from this corner. Repeat for all four corners. There will be no overlap.

To find the intersection you'll have to do some geometry. Every point in the red region is *necessarily* in the blue region, because if a point is maximally away from the corner (0.25 units), it can be at most $\frac{0.25}{\sqrt2}$ away from *both* edges.

So, your answer will be the area of the red region.

Comment: It's possible that the quoted problem is asking for two separate probabilities: $P(D < 1/4)$ and $P(E < 1/4)$.  Your answer is still useful in that case, of course.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't even consider that it could be two separate questions. Edited to reflect this as a possibility. Thanks!